# How to automate deployment of Web Application in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to use WebDeploy in Visual Studio 2010 to deploy our Web Application but it deploy the whole code as it is. Is there an option somewhere like before "Allow this site to be updateable" for WebDeploy?

**EDIT:**
Ok, there is no option available for Web Application and only for Web Site projects.

For Web Application projects, you could add a Web Deployment project which helps you getting a precompiled version, but it doesnt automatically publish it to IIS. Any way to automate that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

u can use the options in the publish website as to get 1. make my site upgradeable 2.make different assembly file for each page 3.pre compiled version when you right click your web app and publish it. Hope i got it right